# can I set style of my container in theme data?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, flutter-widget

To make a rounded corner in my container, I can do something like this

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
  ),
  child: ...
)
```

but I need to do it over and over again whenever I create a container with a rounded corner. can I set it in my Theme data? I can set my appBar theme in theme data like the code below, but I need something similar but for the container. how to do that?

```
final themeData = ThemeData(
  appBarTheme: _appBarTheme,
);

const AppBarTheme _appBarTheme = const AppBarTheme(
  elevation: 2,
  centerTitle: true,
  color: const Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    // center text style
    headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
    // Side text style
    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option here could be isolate a Container and customize this new widget with parameters such as the example bellow.

```
class CustomContainerWdt extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color? color;
  final Widget child;
  final String text;

  const CustomContainerWdt({Key key, this.color, this.child, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text('$text'),
          child,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```